# PHP: Module 'curl' already loaded

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to do a curl POST request in CLI, and it throw this exception :

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

This script works perfectly in local environment (mac os) but when i put it in production (ubuntu 16.04), it throws this exception.

I'm using PHP 5.6 version.

Here is the PHP method :

```
function post_request($url, $data){
    $fields_string =http_build_query($data);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

For information my method is used in the same project (not in cli mode) and works like a charm. the bug is thrown only in CLI mode.

when i look in `/etc/php/5.6/php.ini`, the curl module is only loaded once.

Any Idea ?

Comment: You may find there is a /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/??-curl.ini (Not sure if the ?? is always the same, mine is 20-curl.ini).  If there is one, this is where it's loading the curl configuration the second time.

Comment: Type `php --ini` and it should list the files it's loading and check for above file.

Comment: I have this one with php --ini `/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini`. I just commented the loading line. I do no longer have the warning but wondering if this will not break something else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 sets of config points which may be causing the problem.  You have the php.ini and then you have the directory of config files - conf.d.

Your conf.d file for curl is (for php5.6 cli) - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini.

The rationale seams to be that the conf.d directory may be linked so that all the environments can use the same configuration, but your php.ini can contain a specific configuration for the (for example) CLI version of PHP.

If you want curl to be available and configured the same in all environments, then best to comment out any config parts in the php.ini.

Comment: I tryed both approach and I kept yours because I want curl to be configured the same way.